# Automatic Email notification from ASP.NET with out window service or console app

Tags: asp.net

We have developed application in ASP.net, database is SQL server and deployed in local iis server on client environment. Currently we got new requirements to send notification email to user before 30 days of content expiration.

Client clearly said they will not install and maintain the window service or console application scheduled task on their server.

Is there any way to send the automatic notification from asp.net application? Please share your solution approach to achieve this.

Comment: The question does not have a clear problem we can solve and it doesn't show any effort from your side to try to implement it. As it is the question is too broad, please add your code and what problems you are facing.

Comment: Thanks. i got answer below. that is what exactly i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Quartz.net:
http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

or alternatively add a Timer to the global.asax:

```
    '--Save Translations every 15minutes, starting 15sec after appstart
    Dim TimerDelegate As Threading.TimerCallback = AddressOf SaveTranslationUseage
    Dim MyTimer As Threading.Timer = New Threading.Timer(TimerDelegate, Nothing, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15))
```

and the "worker" Methood:

```
Private Sub SaveTranslationUseage()
    Translator.SaveLastUsages()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Christoph. Quartz.net works fine. is there any cons involved on the Quartz.net, any known issues.